# Loading Calculation for CMOS Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, cmos

the circuit:
[image]

Image source: https://vlsi-design-engineers.blogspot.com/2015/07/cmos-steady-state-electrical-behavior.html

The task is to determine Vout when Vin is low.
My attempt at a solution:
[image]
I said the total voltage was 5-V_th then applied V=IR to find voltage coming out of CMOS circuit, Vout. However, this is wrong and I want to understand the correct method.

Answer (score 3):

Vout is going to have to be more than 3.33 since it's a resistor connected to +5V, right?

Maybe if you think of it this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWMSsu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You should be able to calculate Vout-Vx and then figure Vout, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You calculated the voltage across Rp correctly (0.385V). However, Rp is attached to 5V, not to ground, so you have to take that into account too. If 0.385V drop across Rp, then 5V - 0.385V = 4.615V are present at the gate's output.

Comment: 74HC 50 ohms @ 5V 100 Ohms at 3 V approx https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264515/driving-the-outputs-of-a-buffer/264525#264525

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect values for Rp and Rn the two output complementary Enh. FETs.  CMOS has historically gone from 3k to 50 to 25 ohms. As the RdsOn goes lower the max. Vdd voltage  has gone from 18V to 5.5V to 3.6V and lower so Rn//Rp must also go lower because both are conducting at the middle output voltage.

50 Ohms +/- 33% is my Rule of thumb, but you can get this from 74HCxx data sheet specs for typ or min/max for Vol and Vol @ x mA and Rn = Vol/8mA is typically around 50 Ohms near 5V.

Worst case Rn Rp is much higher at low voltage and high temp.

[image]
You might get more info by searching my answers

"CMOS output impedance user:17574"

Comment: This is quite far from the truth. In modern integrated circuits, you can consider yourself lucky if the standard MOSFET has less than 1k on-resistance (it's typically closer to 10k). It's only the output drivers that are lower resistance (they're physically much bigger MOSFETs; >100x bigger than those in the actual logic gates). 200 Ohms is realistic; it's actually pretty low.

Comment: @Jonathon_S.  , me thinks you misunderstand the facts. CD4000 series was 3K @ 5V and 300 Ohms at 15V

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264515/driving-the-outputs-of-a-buffer/264525#264525

Comment: OP's question is about a CMOS inverter, not a CMOS pin driver. The latter are much stronger, of course, simply because they're physically bigger (gigantic) MOSFETs. Internally, the actual gates and inverters have very high on-resistance - typically many kOhms. Here's one with 20kOhm on-resistance, for example: https://vlsi-iitg.vlabs.ac.in/images/1.3.png Modern VLSI chips (such as CPUs and GPUs) really are built with MOSFETs that can only pass a couple of µA.

Comment: I WAS talking about CMOS inverters being 50 Ohms https://i.stack.imgur.com/K46HY.png Pls do not misunderstand me . If I made an error I will correct it. WIll you?

Comment: You can't generalize from one family of logic ICs to all inverters in the world. The fact is that most CMOS logic gates have output resistances in the kOhm range, driving load capacitances of a few femto-farads. Since OP did not specify that they are using discrete logic, you simply can't say that the values are wrong based on referencing discrete logic ICs. It's far more likely that the book this exercise is from is talking about inverters on a VLSI chip. It's also a fact that no modern university teaches design with discrete logic ICs anymore - they all teach VLSI.

Comment: Jonathon I've been doing this since CMOS came out  when I graduated in 1975. and yes I understand the design rules for all  20 families of CMOS logic SHow me the Vol/Iol=Rn for all CMOS families as I have done and there are wide temp tolerances

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141287/discussion-between-tony-stewart-ee75-and-jonathan-s).